# Exporting Vertices from Blender 2.8 to a .txt-File to import it in ArchiCAD as Terrain

Tags: export, vertices, coordinates

Hey I'm a total Beginner in Blender

I would like to model a certain Terrain in Blender with the Sculpting Mode and export the Vertices to a .txt-File to import it in ArchiCAD as "field surveyor datas" which gives me a Terrain.

I have no clue about programming and unfortunately there is no funtional Add-on for my problem. I've allready  searched in the internet but I haven't found anything helpfull.

Is it possible to Export the coordinates of the Vertices to a sequence like this:

0.0 0.0 0.0

2.0 0.0 2.0

1.0 3.0 1.0

(in each row are the coordinates of one point, every coordinate (xyz) is seperated by a space)

and save it as a .txt file?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

`blender uses python`

if your terrain is meshable here's a snippet to reveal vertices for a mesh.

```
import bpy

def reveal_vertices(mesh):
    verts=mesh.data.vertices
    for i in range(0,len(verts)):
       print('vert['+str(i)+']: '+str(verts[i].co))

mesh = bpy.context.active_object
reveal_vertices(mesh)
```

*about the storing-vert-coordinates-in-a-text-file part that would just be a 
basic python problem but google is always a friend*